# Calling print verb in windows powershell without using Start-Sleep

Tags: powershell, electron

I have an electron app (nodejs) and have a requirement to print pictures from it. I am using the powershell command:

```
$path = "C:\person.jpg";
Start-Process -FilePath $path -Verb Print | Out-Null;
Start-Sleep -s 150;
```

This works but as soon as I remove Start-Sleep, the print window opens for half a second and closes by itself. Then, if I don't do this and the window opens, even after the user presses the close button on the title bar, the powershell process still remains open until the timeout is completed. Is there a way to have this window open and to clean up it's memory when the user closes it?
Many Thans

Comment: It is actually a print preview dialog that shows up. I was expecting it to be open while the user chooses settings e.t.c

Comment: can you run my code in powershell to verify?

Comment: i am using microsoft photos as default. what i am saying is, if you run print from powershell without adding sleep, it shows for a 1 second and closes. sometimes it doesn't show at all. Just try it and see for yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `-Wait` parameter to you `Start-Process` call. From [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6):

> -Wait
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet waits for the specified process and its descendants to complete before accepting more input. This parameter suppresses the command prompt or retains the window until the processes finish.

Otherwise, PowerShell fires up the process and moves on the script execution. That's the reason why you need a `Start-Sleep`. So, change your code to:

```
$path = "C:\person.jpg";
Start-Process -FilePath $path -Verb Print -Wait | Out-Null;
```

if you are using PowerShell 5.x you can also try `Out-Printer´ see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer?view=powershell-5.1) for additional docu.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. this works but sometimes gives an error saying Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required. In any case will mark it as correct.